# Markovian Hawkes Process elementary proof

Tags: conditional-probability, markov-process, point-processes

In the book *An Introduction to the Theory of Point Processes I* by *Vere-Jones* exercise 7.2.5 asks to show that the intensity of a Hawkes process with exponential intensity kernel is Markov. I found various authors stating this property but rarely attempting to prove it or just refering to the memorylessness of the exponential. I would like to prove it with elementary methods and obtained the following 
$ Y(t) = \int_0^t \mathrm{exp}(-\beta(t-s))dN(s)$
$=\int_{t'}^t \mathrm{exp}(-\beta(t-s))dN(s) +  \mathrm{exp}(-\beta(t-t'))\int_0^{t'} \mathrm{exp}(-\beta(t'-s))dN(s)$
$=\int_{t'}^t \mathrm{exp}(-\beta(t-s))dN(s) +  \mathrm{exp}(-\beta(t-t'))Y(t')$

But how do I proceed from here? One idea was to use for $A\in\mathbb{R}^+$ with $A-x=\{a+x| a\in A\}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ that

$\mathbb{P}[Y(t)\in A | Y(t')] = \mathbb{P}\left[\int_{t'}^t \mathrm{exp}(-\beta(t-s))dN(s) +  \mathrm{exp}(-\beta(t-t'))Y(t')\in A |Y(t')\right]$
$=\mathbb{P}\left[\int_{t'}^t \mathrm{exp}(-\beta(t-s))dN(s)\in A-\mathrm{exp}(-\beta(t-t'))Y(t')|Y(t')\right]$

But then I am stuck, because I do not know how to introduce the whole natural filtration $\mathcal{F}_{t'}^Y$ to show the Markov property. Is there maybe a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Comment: I have not found the answer yet.

Comment: Have you found the answer. I have the similar concern too and post it here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4646019/two-issues-regarding-the-markov-process